# PL SQL validating before insertion using trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've recently started to learn a little about databases and I'm trying to make it so a varchar2 will be validated to be all letter characters (no numbers or special characters) before that value will be inserted into the database. I cannot seem to find how exactly to do it, I have a trigger and a function but when I try to insert a string containing special characters it allows it. I was hoping someone could help me out and it would be greatly appreciated..

My code is as follows...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isAlpha (al IN VARCHAR2) RETURN CHAR IS
BEGIN
FOR i in 1..LENGTH(al) LOOP
IF ASCII(SUBSTR(al, i, 1)) < 65 OR ASCII(SUBSTR(al, i, 1)) > 90
THEN RETURN 'F';
END IF;
END LOOP;
RETURN 'T';
END isAlpha;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER valid_name 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ACCOUNT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (ISALPHA(:new.name) = 'F') THEN
raise_application_error(-20001, 'Not valid name');
END IF;
END;
```

It compiles fine but doesn't seem to be working at runtime and I'm fairly new at Oracle SQL so I'm not sure how to debug yet.

Comment: Mysql and sql server are different products from oracle. Pls pay attention to what tags you use!

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/isalpha.php

Comment: Spaces are not alpha characters. I also wanted my own implementation and not to copy someone else's work. I'm trying to learn the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the stupid question. My function works with uppercase and doesn't work on lowercase so when I tried an insert `insert into ACCOUNT (id, cid, name) VALUES (2, 4, 'Brent');` it wouldn't let me because my function would return `F` when it finds the `r`...

Anyways the fix was `IF (ISALPHA(UPPER(:new.name)) = 'F') THEN`